# Blank Admin page after install with no errors messages or redirect

Tags: magento2, admin, page, white-screen, blank

I am attempting to install a Magento 2.4.1 solution that it's already in production. I've previously installed other Magento solutions that were similar and had no issues. In this case, the install process goes without errors, but as soon as I try going to *localhost/admin* I get a completely white page, no errors or anything useful and the URL which should redirect to the admin page does not change. URL Rewrites are enabled. The apache logs as well as Magento's logs display no errors, enabling `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `bootstrap.php` does nothing either. I've already done the necessary changes to Magento's code because I am running it on XAMPP, Windows. To install I followed [this guide](https://javapocalypse.medium.com/install-magento-2-4-on-windows-10-2021-a0c433e4ffc4). So the proper changes were done in `Gd2.php`, `Validator.php` and `PluginListGenerator.php` files. The PHP version is correct, I'm using 7.3 and as I mentioned above, URL rewrites are enabled. Also, the cache was cleared and flushed, the `.htaccess` file is in place, I've used the one in `/pub` folder and also got fed up searching the internet for this. What could be causing it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out eventually. Turns out the issue was due to the `env.php` file. The `--backend-frontname` was actually causing the issue. I had this as `Admin` instead of `admin`, so this should have been all lower-case. So to fix it, I went and opened `{my-magento-folder}\app\etc\env.php` and adjusted the file like this.

This chunk of code

```
'backend' => [
    'frontName' => 'Admin'
]
```

I've changed it to this

```
'backend' => [
    'frontName' => 'admin'
]
```

After saving the file and reloading the page the issue was solved. If someone can leave a comment and explain why the casing is important here, please do. Hopefully this helps someone in need. Good luck!

Comment: Though using caps with frontname shouldn't be an issue, this might hide something else. It made me search where the frontname was stored by magento but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: That's what I thought too, casing shouldn't have caused any issues, but it does. I tried changing it back to 'Admin' just to confirm and sure enough, using a capital letter caused it to break again. I also tried on a different solution that was already working and messing with that broke the other solution too. It could be as you say, there might be something else under the hood, but one thing is clear, this is case-sensitive. I will research that and if I manage to determine why is this, I will do an edit to the post.

Comment: When you changed the frontname i think you have to di compile and deploy static again. I think the way should be to go check what the magento command that changed the frontname does in order to see where she handle this...but anyway you got it threw all is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your database the result of `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like '%base_url%'` and make sure the url you enter match the url magento is expected.
Make also sure the url is matching your docker installation if you have some and eventually your host.

If you work with multiple magento instance what might also happen is that you didn't close one of your instance and your magento project might hit the database of an other one ? It actually did happen to me one due to a bad docker configuration.

Try to setup a `die('test');` in your entry point to be sure you hit the first file....cause if you don't obviously the display errors won't be interprated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's not it. The base URL is fine, I am not using docker and I am not working with multiple instances. Only one instance runs at any given time. Also the breakpoints do get hit in index.php so errors do get enabled.